# Tags about safety

Tags: discussion, tagging

Some questions about food safety and kitchen safety are tagged with [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety). Is retagging questions about food safety with the tag [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) to [food-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety) and leaving all kitchen safety questions with the [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) tag a good idea? Or should we introduce a new [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety) tag and leave the [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) tag for both cases? Or should we even clean up the [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the relatively small number of questions tagged with [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) I would say the food safety related questions should be retagged to [food-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety) as the sheer number of questions already tagged with [food-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety) indicates there is community consensus on how those questions should be tagged.

Then I would recommend creating the tag [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety) and merging the [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) into it which would result in the remaining questions being tagged appropriately under [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety)  and aliasing [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) to it as a synonym. This would prevent future tagging of questions with just the more generic [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety).

Comment: Worth noting an appropriate tag wiki entry should also be created for kitchen-safety so it is clear when to use that vs. food-safety.

Answer (score 1):

I just independently rediscovered this. I renamed [safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) to [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety), but without creating a synonym. That'd be awkward for an ambiguous tag like this; obviously some people type "safety" thinking food safety, and others are thinking kitchen safety, so we don't want to always turn it into [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety).

We still need to go through everything now tagged [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety) and correct it to [food-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety) as appropriate.

Comment: There are still plenty of [safety] questions out there, I'll check them (I was going to ask a meta question about this tags)