# Do we need both the "cooking-safety" and "ktichen safety" tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is a [documented reason](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/tags-about-safety) for having a [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety) tag: it's for differentiating from [food-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-safety) questions. I today realized that we also have a [cooking-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking-safety) tag, and I can't think of a good reason for that.

Neither of the two tags has a tag wiki or tag info. Both have a modest number of questions (97 for [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety) and 31 for [cooking-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking-safety)), and some of those questions even have both tags.

I don't think these tags denote different concepts, nor do I see a difference in their practical use. So the question is, do we need both, or should we synonymize and keep only one, and if so, which of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd keep [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety) - [cooking-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking-safety) can very easily be read as encompassing both food and kitchen, while [kitchen-safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-safety) is a bit less ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I implemented the merge today.